# Swift - Nothing happens when I try to make a phone call programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, url, phone-call

On button click I try to make a phone call using this code, but just nothing(despite printing number) happens:

```
@IBAction func MakeACall(_ sender: Any) {

    let mobilenumber = selectedContact?.Mobile
    print(mobilenumber)
    var h = "03425678962" as String?
    guard let abc=h else { return }
    let phoneFallback = "telprompt://\(abc)"
    let fallbackURl = URL(string:phoneFallback)!
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(fallbackURl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(fallbackURl)
    }
}
```

I thought that there may be some problem with mobilenumber I'm passing from different file that's why I created var h and used it instead of mobilenumber but still just nothing happened. If anyone could give me some advice on it I would really appreciate that as I just started learning Swift this week.

Just in case I just wanted to mention that I tried to use function canOpenURL before I try to openURL but it caused me error:"This app is not allowed to query for scheme telprompt". I added telprompt to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in source code of my info.plist but it didn't helped and I was still getting this error.

Comment: Are you trying it on real device or simulator?

Comment: On simulator. I thought it will work properly on simulator as when I was creating something similar on android in java, using their emulator I could create intent and make a call on it.

Comment: That is the issue. It is not working on simulator.